# Beginner's C++: How do I pass a list as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, list, function

I am trying to make a user-generate search function for an entry-level C++ function. The function should take a list and three integers, but it won't recognize the list. I can pass int[] but whenever i give it a name such as "int[] list" it throws the program off.

EDIT: Here is the warning I get: expected a ')'. And then it goes over the variable parameters names and says "first is unidentified", "last is unidentified", and so on. Did a few ninja edits to show more of the code here. Sorry!

I feel like this is very elementary for C++ users, but I don't get it! I do not want to use pointers quite yet in this program.

```
int binSearch(int[] first, int target, int first, int last) {
    int middle = (first + last) / 2; 
    cout << "Entering binSearch: list[first]=" + list[first] +
        ", list[last]=" + list[last] + ", "; 
    cout << "list[middle]=" + list[middle];
}

int main() {

     int list[10]; 

    // creating sorted array 
    cout << "The list is "; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list[i] = 2 * i + 1; 
        cout << list[i] + " "; 
    }
    cout << endl; 

    // prompt user to enter key 
    int key; 
    cout << "Enter a key: "; 
    cin >> key; 
    int index = binSearch(list, 10, key, 0, 10 - 1); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"give it a name such as "int[] list" it throws the program off."*? Please provide a proper [mcve] and include all error messages

Comment: Use `std::vector`

Comment: you're not defining what list is in your program, at least, as far as we can see... as @UnholySheep suggested you should provide us with more code to test

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on in your code. I think you mean to name your array list? Which might be a problem because you seem to be using namespace std and list is in that namespace

Comment: When you say list, it means `std::list<int>` to me, which is probably not what you mean.  Instead, it sounds like you want to pass an array?

Comment: You typed `int[] first` instead of `int[] list`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, arrays are declared with the brackets after the variable name:

```
int binSearch(int list[], int target, int first, int last)
```

Note that I also changed the first parameter from `first` to `list`.